# Unable to start activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

When i  run the code on my phone logcat says "01-12 12:39:00.706: E/AndroidRuntime(12206): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.app/android.app.activity3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Heres my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity

            android:name=".AndroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".activity2"
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                   android:label="@string/app_name" >

         </activity>

         <activity android:name=".activity3"
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                   android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>

         <activity android:name=".next" ></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your app's package name is [`android.app`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/package-summary.html)? O.o

Comment: are you sure you put activity3 in the package android.app?

Comment: Yes all 3 activities are in android.app package and activity2 worksfine!

Comment: Please share the code where you are launching activity3.

Answer (score 0):

go to mainfest editor -> Activities and see if it shows error. If it do then browse your activity class and save file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this... hope it helps.

<activity 
        android:name=".activity3" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.activity3"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have declared activity3 class at android.app package. This class must extends from Activity class.